# 2d array gamemap line numbering

Tags: java, tostring

I'm trying to create a 2d gamefield with line numbering, but I can't get my head around how to code the numbering correctly in java.

What I have so far is only working up to an imput of rows and columns to 9.

For any two digit number or higher it's not displaying the map correctly as I don't have enough space. I could add to block let's say two blank spaces so the line numbering can go up to hundreds, but I'm trying to get a map that isn't restricted.

Any help is much appreciated. 
Here is what I have now:

```
public String toString() {
    String output;
    output = "gamemap:\n  ";
    for (int j = 0; j < this.y; j++) { // loop over columns
        output += j;
    }
    output += "\n *";

    for (int j = 0; j < this.y; j++) { // loop over columns
        output += "*";
    }
    output += "*\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < this.x; i++) { // loop over rows
        output += i + "*";
        for (int j = 0; j < this.y; j++) { // loop over columns
            output += this.map[i][j];
        }   
        output += "*\n"; 
    }
    output += " *";

    for (int j = 0; j < this.y; j++) { // loop over columns
        output += "*";
    }
    output += "*\n";

    output += "The player has "+ this.player.lives + " lives left.";
    return output;
}
```

Comment: what is this? this.x? this.y?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but consider changing `output` to a StringBuilder to avoid all of those String concatenation operations.

Comment: Can you add the expected output as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private String getPaddedNumber(int number, int maxNumber) {
    if(maxNumber <= number) return Integer.toString(number);

    int buffer = number;
    while((buffer /= 10) != 0 & (maxNumber /= 10) != 0) {
        //nothing
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(maxNumber != 0) {
        sb.append('0'); //alternatively sb.append(' ');
        maxNumber /= 10;
    }

    return sb.append(number).toString();
}
```

number is the line number you want to display, maxNumber would be the number of lines you have (or more precicely, the highest line index you have)